# Only apply condition if previous element contains a class

Tags: css

Sorry if this is a bit too specific, but I don't really want to use jQuery for this.
Given the following HTML template:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="hint">Hint displays on focus using Bootstrap Material Design</div>
    <!-- Nothing special applies to this because this is the first row -->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <!-- This will have a margin-top of 20px -->
    <!-- This doesn't have a hint so the following .row doesn't need the extra 10px -->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <!-- Regular margin-top of 10px -->
  </div>

</form>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.hint {
  display: none;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

For every `.row` that contains `.hint`, I want to apply an additional margin of 10px for the next `.row`, so the `.hint` can display properly and not overflow on the row (`.hint` appears below the text input when the input is focused).

Psuedocode of what I want:

```
.row[previous .row contains .hint] {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Is this possible with CSS or will I have to use Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with CSS as you can't select based on the child of a previous element.

Comment: Ah damn, guess I'll resort to jQuery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you make a *brief* demo of what actually happens we might be able to offer alternative css solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same spacing can be included by using `padding-bottom: 10px` for the `hint` element.

```css
.hint {
  display: none;
}
.row input:focus + .hint {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="hint">Hint displays on focus using Bootstrap Material Design</div>
    <!-- Nothing special applies to this because this is the first row -->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <!-- This will have a margin-top of 20px -->
    <!-- This doesn't have a hint so the following .row doesn't need the extra 10px -->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="text">
    <!-- Regular margin-top of 10px -->
  </div>

</form>
```